# How can I sort my ArrayList? And select the best one

Tags: java, arraylist

Sorry this has probably been answered somewhere but I'm pretty new to Java and I can't apply other answers I have found to the work I'm doing.

So I have an ArrayList which stores locations of pieces it can take on that particular turn.

```
ArrayList<Move> legalTakes = new ArrayList<Move>();
```

A move has a co-ordinate from (x1,y1) and a co-ordinate to (x2,y2) which is where the piece it will be taking is at.

```
moveInput = new Move(pieceToMove, x1, y1, x2, y2, false);
```

From calling a method (getPiece) I can take the x2,y2 and see which piece is at that location and find the value of that piece.

```
for (Move m : legalTakes) {  //for all of the possible takes that turn...
    Piece occPieceToTake = this.getBoard().getPiece(m.getX2(),m.getY2());
    int pieceValue = this.getBoard().getPiece(m.getX2(),m.getY2()).getValue(occPieceToTake.getChar());
    System.err.println("-- WORTH : "+pieceValue);           
}
```

From this is it possible to order my ArrayList based on the value returned by pieceValue? So if a king is returned with a value of 6, I can select that over a pawn which will return a value of 1?

Hope this is sufficient information..if not please let me know.

Comment: `Collections.sort(list, Comparator);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can sort you list by doing this,

```
ArrayList<ListObj> list = new ArrayList<ListObj>();

   Collections.sort(list, Comparator);
//or 
       Collections.sort(list);
```

have a look on [comparator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm) if you are unsure about its working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comparator for this. First, you need to create a class implementing the `Comparator` interface. Then you can use the `Collections` utility class:

```
Collections.sort(list, new MyComparator());
```

Comment: For an `ArrayList`, you might need `Collections.sort`